# Count data from one table where table column = row number

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I use SQL query to count in table t where column1 or column2 or column3 or column 4 = row numbers. example

Table t

```
c1  c2  c3  c4   c5  c6
 2   4   7  10  22  35
 1   3   7  22  35  39
 1   2   21 30  35  36
```

Result

```
RowNumbe  count
1           2
2           2
3           1
4           1
5           0
6           0
7           2
8           0
9           0
10          1 etc
```

Comment: You might want to try to explain that a little better...

Comment: No getting clear idea what you exactly want!

Comment: please add some sample data with fiddle

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor schema design. Remember: A database table is NOT a spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

You can use do `left join` with union sub-query :

```
select seq.RowNumber, count(cols.col) as cnt
from ( select 1 as RowNumber union all
       select 2 union all
       . . . 
       select 10
     ) as seq left join
     ( select t.col1 as col
       from table t union all
       select t.col2
       from table t union all
       . . .
       select t.col6
       from table t
     ) as cols
     on seq.RowNumber = cols.col
group by seq.RowNumber
```